# Android window WindowLeaked - Activity has leaked window that was originally added here

Tags: android, multithreading

im try to show ProgressDialog in side the thread.but when the app run Progressdialog will crach and it give this Exception

> android.view.WindowLeaked:
>   Activity com.testApp.CaptureSignature has leaked window
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{528dd504
>   V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-949,480} that was originally added here

error getting when line executing

```
pDialog.show();

public void syncing(final int sel){

        if(sel==1){
            ProgressDialo pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CaptureSignature.this);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setProgress(0);
            pDialog.setOnDismissListener(new MyCustomDialog.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                    doaftersync(pDialog.getProgress(),sel);

                }

            }); 
            pDialog.setMessage("Syncing Deliveries.Please wait..");
            pDialog.show();
            Thread  background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {

                       progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());


                       int stat = deliveryup();
                        if(stat==1){

                            try {
                                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListner);
                            } catch (Exception e2) {
                            }

                        }else{
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            return;

                        }

                        progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                         int isustat=issueup();
                            if(isustat==0){
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                return;

                            }

                        progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());

                        int locstat=locationup();
                            if(locstat==0){
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                                return;

                            }

                        cleanup();

                        progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        return;
                   }
                });
             background.start();

        }

    }

    // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            pDialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
        }
    };
```

Any Help .. !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dismiss Your `ProgressDialog` in Main Thread Using `Handler` or Using `runOnUiThread()` Method

Maybe You get exception because Progress dialog is running while Your `Activity` is destroyed. you should dismiss dialog when `Activity` is destroyed

Comment: Thank you..my activity is destroy before progress dialog run thats the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Do all your UI actions in a UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the safe way :

```
    if(dialog.isShowing()){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```